# How to get up-to-date likedCount integer value from a object saved in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have such data structure in firebase

```
posts: {
  post1-uid: {
    likedCount: 10
    ... other properties ...
  }
  post2-uid: {
    likedCount: 2
    ... other properties ...
  }
}
```

I'd like to automatically fetch again the `likedCount` for any given post (for example post1) in javascript whenever its value changes.

I attempt to use

```
var likedCount;
post1Ref.on("child_change", snapshot => {
    likedCount = snapshopt.val();
});
```

But the listener is also triggered when `other properties` in `post1` are updated. Do I need to add `if else` condition? It seems that I am on the wrong track..
What is the elegant way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a listener on a very small piece of data, then just structure your data differently and point your reference at the new parent of the likedCount.

```
posts: {
  post1-uid: {
    metrics: {
      likedCount: 10
    },
    ... other properties ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is concise and to the point. It requiresme to change the bare minimum yet achieves the goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `child_` events trigger when the direct child node of where you attach the listener change (or is added, or removed). You cannot trigger them for a specific property.

If you only want to trigger when the `likedCount` changes, you could model your data to have a separate list of liked counts:

```
likedCounts
  post1-uid1: 10
  post1-uid2: 2
```

Now you can attach listeners to `likedCounts` and just be informed on changes to that value:

```
ref.child("likedCounts").on("child_change", snapshot => {
    let postKey = snapshot.key;
    let likedCount = snapshot.val();
});
```

Comment: but still we don't know from which post the `snapshot.val()` is coming from. When user opens `post1` page, he needs only the likedCount of `post1`.

Comment: The key of the post that triggered the event is available in `snapshot.key`. If you need access to the rest of the post itself, you can look it up under `/posts` with that.